# mysql order by followed by group by

Tags: mysql

so i'm about to migrate my server to a new machine. i install the newer version of mysql 5.7.13 on the new machine while the old one mysql 5.5.13. and there is this one query that doesn't work like it works before
with the same data as previous server

```
select * 
  from
     ( select * 
         from user_config 
        where username like '%' 
          and updatetime <= '2500-01-01 00:00:00' 
        order 
           by updatetime desc
     ) x 
 group 
    by username;
```

the mysql 5.5.13 works as i want, it load the newest configuration setting of every user. but the 5.7.13 instead load the oldest configuration setting of every user

why is this happening?

i tried to run the subquery and it works both fine but when i combine to the query above it doesn't work

example data

```
username|value|updatetime
a       |  100|2014-01-01 00:00:00
b       |   85|2014-06-01 00:00:00
a       |  150|2016-05-01 00:00:00
c       |   50|2016-06-01 00:00:00
c       |   75|2016-06-23 00:00:00
```

result i need is

```
a|150
b|85
c|75
```

Comment: The syntax you are using is a non-standard MySQL extension to ANSI SQL. It will return one random value from the group for each non grouped column. So in essence it is pure luck that you got the first row of your subquery. Since the row chosen is unspecified it may change from version to version. This query is really bad design. Change your query to not depend on undocumented behaviour (5.5 happened to chose the first row but this is not part of the specification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT username
            , MAX(updatetime) updatetime
         FROM my_table
        GROUP 
           BY username
     ) y
    ON y.username = x.username
   AND y.updatetime = x.updatetime;
```

Comment: @Msfvtp Glad someone's paying attention. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Use order by and limit 1 in sub-query to get the desired result :

```
select * from user_config t1
Where updatetime=(select updatetime from user_config x where x.username=t1.username order by updatetime desc limit 1);
```

Comment: i edited my post with example, if i put group by before order by it load the oldest configuration for every user

Comment: Ok i understand the problem now and i will update my answer asap.

Comment: what is the t1 ? Think you forgot some line?

Comment: In compare with Strawberry's answer in performance subject: my query is faster when limited number of users must be evaluated and when all rows must be returned, I think Strawberry's answer is faster than mine.

Comment: In practice a correlated subquery rarely beats an uncorrelated one. Also, note that you forgot `DESC`.